# AWS get-object-acl for multiple objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have looked and can't find my answer (if it's even possible).

Using get-object-acl, I am trying to view multiple objects in a folder in S3 at the same time.  I can view one item using:

```
$ aws s3api get-object-acl --bucket stores --key cloths/shoes
```

there are 2 objects in that folder so i can run the below for the other

```
$ aws s3api get-object-acl --bucket stores --key cloths/pants
```

I'd like to be able to get a listing of both by running:

```
$ aws s3api get-object-acl --bucket stores --key cloths/*
```

or something like that but * does no work in this case.  Just shows the permissions of the cloths folder.

In this example, anyway to show both (or however many files under the folder) at the same time?

Thanks !

Comment: S3 doesn't have folders.  The underlying S3 API only accepts an S3 object to query, so you have no option other than to enumerate the objects and get the ACL for each object in turn.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72297750/check-file-permissions-for-each-file-on-a-s3-bucket-recursive) for an example of how to do that in Python.

Comment: FYI, these days it is recommended _not_ to use object ACLs. See: [Disabling ACLs for all new buckets and enforcing Object Ownership - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ensure-object-ownership.html)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it's only achievable using pipes

```
aws s3 ls s3://[YOUR_BUCKET]/[DIRECTORY] --recursive | awk '{cmd="aws s3api get-object-acl --bucket [YOUR_BUCKET] --key "$4; system(cmd)}' > outputfile.json
```

`$4` Gets the `--key` returned in the `ls` command in the previous pipe

It gets the directory's ACL though.